# Run Laravel Jobs in multiple intances

Tags: php, laravel, docker, web-deployment

I have a Laravel application that is running some Jobs on background but I have multiple instances of the application.

One of these jobs sends emails to some records in my database but it was sending multiple emails due to the multiple instances, right now I'm solving the issue setting an offset inside of the execution time and adding an status field to set the records that are being processed as busy.

What I would like to know if somebody has another approach to solve this kind of issue when the system has multiple instances.

Thanks in advance.
If you want more information just let me know.

Comment: did you look at Laravel Queues ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues

Comment: Yes, this is a background process but how to avoid that instances take the same records when the job is launched?

Comment: I think this does not occur, @Mirdrack.

Comment: That is the point of a queue, when a server takes the job in the queue they mark it as checked out so other task runners don't grab it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I posted this there was a real option to handle this.
I used record in the database to lock the execution of the job that was being processed by other instance.

The performance of this can be improved using a centralized cache service storing a key with a value that identifies the job and being checked at the beginning of the job execution.

The requirement of this solution is that you are going to need centralized cache service like redis or memcache.